# how to pick up data from web page threw Shortcuts iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, shortcut

I would like an iOS shortcuts which goes threw my two cryptos wallet on webpages, then which collect the amount and finally add the two values in a Note.
I have no clue how to do that so if you have some ideas or hints it could be super great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

run javascript on safari and get the amount value, then use shortcut add them to the note